# Sortable and Seralize

Tags: jquery, serialization, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a very simple example of a list of buttons that can be dragged to a list.

I need to pass the item added to the list to my DB but there is a problem with my ajax because in the console after the button is dropped the GET array is still empty.

I am new to Jquery and I have been looking for answers everywhere so if anyone could let me know what I am missing it would be appreciated so much

Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">

        <style>
        .row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
}

.dropme {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.dropme div {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.highlight {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px dotted #fff09f;
    background: #fffef5;
}
    </style>

    </head>

     <body class="layout-boxed bg_style_2">

<div class="row">
    <div class="button" data-item="10">Item 10</div>
    <div class="button" data-item="11">Item 11</div>
    <div class="button" data-item="12">Item 12</div>
</div>

<div class="dropme">
    <div>List Item 1</div>
    <div>List Item 2</div>
    <div>List Item 3</div>
    <div>List Item 4</div>
    <div>List Item 5</div>

</div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script> 

<!-- end: JAVASCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY --> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.sortable.js"></script>
<script>
$('.button').draggable({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    connectWith: '.dropme',
    helper: 'clone',
    opacity: 0.5,
    zIndex: 10
});

$('.dropme').sortable({
    connectWith: '.dropme',
    cursor: 'pointer'
}).droppable({
    accept: '.button',
    activeClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $li = $('<div>').html('List ' + ui.draggable.html());
        $li.appendTo(this);
    }
})        

var data = $('.dropme').sortable('serialize');
        // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'scripts/enroll_myt.php'
        });
;

</script>
```

Thanks so much for looking!

Comment: Why is dropme connected with dropme? Also, the stray semicolon at the bottom of the code you provided belongs after the end parenthesis before var data = ... I suspect that the out-of-place semi-colon could be throwing something off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of creating a JSFiddle that breaks down the main concept... You were close. Basically, serialize will stringify the div IDs (which are missing from your code snippet).

```
$(".dropme").sortable({
    cursor: 'pointer'
}).droppable({
    accept: '.button',
    activeClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $li = $('<div>').html("List " + ui.helper.text()).attr("data-button-id", ui.helper.find("div").attr("id"));
        $li.appendTo(this);
    }
});

$('.button').draggable({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    helper: function() {
        return $("<div class='help' />").append($(this).clone().removeClass("button"));
    },
    opacity: 0.75,
});

$("#send-btn").click(function() {
    var arr = [];
    $(".dropme div").each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).attr("data-button-id"));
    });

    alert(arr);
});
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/blake_neal/0Lvfuhvx/10/).

Comment: Hi Blake,

Sorry for being slow on the uptake but in your fiddle I do not see the alert change when the button or added or nothing in the console that indicates the data array has been changed.  Am I reading the fiddle wrong?

Comment: Check it out again. Tried to make it super clear this time. Basically, I modified the helper draggable so it wraps the actual button <div> data, and upon drop it creates a new line in the droppable/sortable which retains the button's ID in a data attribute (data-button-id). When you hit the "Send" button, I simply look in the .dropme for all children divs, loop through each and add each data-button-id value to the array and then alert the whole array. You can also push them to the array as strings, which will work well with the server you're sending the result to. Hope that helps